# What exactly does memcache.dbpath set in php-memcache?

Tags: php, memcached

I have `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.16` with `php5-memcache 3.0.6-1` (not php-memcache**d** extension, "without d").

In its `/etc/php5/conf.d/memcache.ini` file there's a parameter for

```
memcache.dbpath="/var/lib/memcache"
```

What exactly is it used for?
I have searched official documentatoin, but found no reference to this setting.

I'm not asking about *memcached server*, but rather PHP's driver for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this and any other parameters do absolutely nothing in `php5-memcache` module. There is no mention of them anywhere in the source code for this module.

This seems like one of those dumb things where somebody on the internet posted it and everybody else just blindly repeats it without actually checking if it's true.